# Fail to parse on a json stream using node-fetch

Tags: node.js, stream, node-fetch, jsonstream

I run the sample code from `node-fetch` stream feature.
Sometime it can successfully parse the chunk, sometimes return error msg `SyntaxError: Unexpected token { in JSON at position 312`

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

async function main() {
  const response = await fetch('https://httpbin.org/stream/3');
  try {
    for await (const chunk of response.body) {
      console.log(JSON.parse(chunk.toString()));
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.stack);
  }
}

main()
```

Anyone know why? Can I rely on the chunk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By requesting `https://httpbin.org/stream/3`, the server sends the data splitting into 3 chunks via stream.  The client (in this case your node script) keeps connection with the server and keep receiving the data and splits them into chunks.

The `node-fetch` simply splits data into chunks every time when a single asynchronous task is completed as you can see here: [line 199 of body.js](https://github.com/node-fetch/node-fetch/blob/136a5f143329f383594fd5510dcd893cc91c93aa/src/body.js#L193).

So if the splitted data arrives so quickly that the asynchronous task receives multiple chunks of data within a single node's event loop, `node-fetch` receives multiple jason data.

That's when the error occurs.  Run the following code with `console.log` added.  Then you can confirm that when error occurs, the multiple jason objects are kept in a `chunk`.

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

async function main () {
  const response = await fetch('https://httpbin.org/stream/3');
  try {
    for await (const chunk of response.body) {
      console.log("------chunk-----\n", chunk.toString());
      console.log("Char at 310 -- 315", chunk.toString().substring(310, 315));
      console.log(JSON.parse(chunk.toString()));
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.stack);
  }
}

main()
```

For this site, you can split the data by yourself when the error occurs as follows.

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

async function main () {
  const response = await fetch('https://httpbin.org/stream/3');
  try {
    for await (const chunk of response.body) {
      try {
        console.log(JSON.parse(chunk.toString()));
      } catch (_) {
        console.log("------ Handling multiple chunks ------");
        chunk.toString().split("\n").slice(0, -1).forEach(d => console.log(JSON.parse(d)));
      }
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.stack);
  }
}
main()
```

When you use Fetch API with a browser, you can actually write your own [ReadableStreamReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Streams_API/Using_readable_streams) and implement the strategy how to handle the splitted data.

**Update:**

You can simply use `stream-json` library's [jsonl Parser](https://github.com/uhop/stream-json/wiki/jsonl-Parser) as follows:

```
const { parser: jsonlParser } = require('stream-json/jsonl/Parser');

async function main () {
  const response = await fetch('https://httpbin.org/stream/5');
  response.body.pipe(jsonlParser())
    .on('data', ({ key, value }) => console.log(value))
    .on('end', () => console.log("Parsing done."))
    .on('error', err => console.log(err.message));
}

main();
```